# Как добавить кастомизированный адаптер RecyclerView в outState в методе onSaveInstanceState что бы пересоздавать RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate

В приложении есть RecyclerView, в нём какие-то item сохраняются пользователем и живут.После того как приложение закрывается, RecyclerView ожидаемо становится пустым при открытии. Необходимо что бы при открытии приложения состояние RecyclerView сохранялось? Хочу делать это в onSaveInstanceState , сохранять адаптер и потом в onCreate его переопределять.Как это сделать?Какие плюсы и минусы этого метода? Как сделали бы вы?

Comment: Если вам нужно сохранять состояние списка между закрытиями приложения, то SaveInstanceState() для этого не подходит, так как этот инструмент хранит данные довольно короткое время и используется, как правило, для сохранения состояния при переходах между активити в пределах работы одной сессии одного приложения. Данные при этом хранятся в оперативной памяти. Для более длительного периода используется хранение в базе данных, запись в файл, SharedPreferences и прочее с записью в постоянную память. Могу порекомендовать работать с Room

Comment: Применение Room для 1-2 задач в приложении по сохранению состояний пары полей и одного RecyclerView не слишком будет?

Comment: А что у вас там в списке отображается, деяток айтемов? Вообще, куда сохранять - решать вам, основновная мысль, что между закрытиями приложения нужно записывать в постоянную память, а не хранить в оперативной. savedInstanceState() не записывает в постоянную память.

Answer (score 2):

Получаете состояние(`state`) методом `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();`
и сохраняете в методе `onSaveInstanceState()` фрагмента или активити. Там же сохраняете список элементов.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(ARRAY_LIST_RESULTS, list);
    outState.putParcelable(LIST_STATE, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

При восстановлении, получаете из бандла сохраненный список и скармливаете адаптеру, а также восстанавливаете `state`.

```
list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(ARRAY_LIST_RESULTS);
Parcelable listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_STATE);
if(listState != null) { 
    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
}
```

Если у вас фрагмент, то установите флаг `setRetainInstance(true);` и состояние экрана должно сохраняться и восстанавливаться без дополнительного кода. Но это не точно)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Comment: List элементов которые видны в RecyclerView лежит в классе адаптера.То есть его нет в фрагменте, в котором сам непосредственно RecyclerView располагается. А ещё не увидел где в коде "скармливается сохранённый список адаптеру".Спасибо за ответ,я только учусь

Comment: и list даже если удастся создать в этом фрагменте, то это не просто List а List<UserInfo>, то есть с объектами созданного мной класса

Comment: В чем проблема достать список из адаптера?  "Скармливать" - имею ввиду передать список в адаптер. Список может быть с любыми объектами. Но чтобы сохранить в методе putParcelableArrayList, объект должен реализовывать интерфейс parcelable

Comment: Parcelable listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_STATE); это тоже не проходит, крашится приложение с жалобой на эту строку. Это всё потому что надо для класса, List с экземплярами которого передаю делать parcelable или serializable?